# How can I delete Google drive file on android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am a developer and currently working on google drive API on android.

I can query and create file/folder from my app using GoogleApiClient; however, I cannot delete the files from my app.

After I google it and I found out that the newest google drive Android API has not supported it yet.

So, are there other ways to delete files from android app?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer is here - SO 22295903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295903/how-to-delete-a-file-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-android-api), just combine with [the old API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete). Or wait, DELETE has been [promised soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369573/trash-delete-in-new-google-drive-android-api).

In SO 22295903, there is a mention of reverting to the [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/). I have not done it myself, but I think you would take the resource ID, *DriveId.getResourceId()* and apply it to the [trash](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/trash) or [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete) method. But it is only an untested idea, so don't shoot me.

Comment: There is still no 'delete' AFAK. But I am not current in GDAA since I switched to the RESTful a while ago. You can work around it by creating your own 'mytrash' folder, empty the file content, optionally rename the file (i.e. prefix + orig filename), and move it to the 'mytrash'. But all your logic must adjust (like search results filtered by parentfolder != 'mytrash' or checking the prefix, etc.) Quite messy. If you mix REST trash and GDAA, you'll run into timing issues (you have no control over GDAA changes propagation)