# Google drive Android SDK does not see files created using the web UI

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Inside an Android App, I'm using the code below to list the contents of a folder

```
Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, driveId).listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(listChildrenResultCallback);
```

While this lists contents uploaded by my app correctly, I do not see content created using the web UI.

Is this expected ?

Comment: maybe linked to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408579/drivefolder-listchildren-not-showing-all-its-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAA (Google Drive Android Api) supports only the FILE scope, i.e. it can only work with objects (folders / files) that the app created. If you want to access files created by other apps (web UI) you have to use [RESTful Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/). See the [scopes here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes).

Comment: Damn, now I have to redo everything using the REST api... Thanks for the clear answer though.