# List children in AppData folder on GoogleDrive across devices/different installs

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

My app needs to list the files of the AppFolder in GoogleDrive.

It seems that when I create some files in the app, then uninstall the app and try to list the children again, I can't see any files there anymore, even though the folder for my app says I have hidden app data.

I am currently using:

```
DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient);
DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult = folder.listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).await();
```

to retrieve the app folder. 
Why can I not see the children again in another install and what's the solution?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Sometimes when I run the app, it lists the files correctly, and sometimes it doesn't. I've tried to understand why that is, but it seemed totally random to me. Surely the Drive service should be reliable?

UPDATE2: This is partially solved using the requestSync. I call it before accessing the appFolder, is that ok? Or should I call it after? Or no difference there?
But the problem I have now is that I get a "Sync request rate limit exceeded". 
However, I only make the request once per a connection session, so I don't understand why it says I exceeded the quota, which apparently is 10M per day, and 10/sec...
Any help please?

Comment: The 10/sec rate limit you mention applies to the REST API. requestSync() on the Android API is rate limited to 1 per minute. Could you file a bug on our issue tracker so we can dig into this further: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=API%3DDriveAndroid

Comment: See the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408579/drivefolder-listchildren-not-showing-all-its-children

Comment: @Daniel thanks, I didn't realize that there would be different limits, this seems to explain the issue.