# Query folder name

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using this code for search a folder

```
Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, MainActivity.FOLDER_NAME)).build();
Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query).setResultCallback(metadata);
```

and on

```
final ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadata = new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                if (result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount() == 0) {
                ….
            }
```

result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount() return me 8.

When from telephone(with Drive App) I removed everyone folders whose name was MainActivity.FOLDER_NAME

What’s wrong ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you've run into the pitfall reported in [SO 21369573](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369573/trash-delete-in-new-google-drive-android-api), and discussed as a [Github issue here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/3). You are seeing trashed/deleted files/folders LONG AFTER they have been deleted by other apps (like Web Drive...). And there is no 'trash/delete' function in the GDAA at the moment. The issue has been around since the introduction of the GDAA (4 months now). I had to resort to manually rename the files/folders in Google drive before manually deleting them in my test environment to be able to debug stuff.

*Does any of the [Google development team / support members](https://developers.google.com/drive/support) care to comment? The page says "Ask a Question about the Google Drive SDK".*