# Drive API for Android is broken, right?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

As at August 2015, the 'Drive API for Android' is not functioning as (loosely)documented, is effectively broken. The main sore points are as follows:

1) An app sharing the same APP_ID and logged in with the same Google User is *meant to be able to* find and access the same files [as Google indicate](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/KKi3N7ubjyZ) (e.g. appX on device1 creates a folder named 'blahblah' (where no 'blahblah' folder already exists in the User's Drive), appX on device2 should be able to find that folder and upload/download files from it also...however this is not the case (or if it does work, it is intermittent and mostly not working at all)). This remains the case even after (many) requestSync calls and over 72hours of allowing Drive to sync itself.

2) A trashed folder is not observed as trashed, even after a requestSync call has succeeded. Such a trashed folder will still have isTrashed==false.

3) A permanently trashed folder (i.e. it is GONE from Drive, it is never coming back). Can still be found and "successfully" have folders and files created within it, however writing to such a file's contents will always yield a failure in Completion Event Service. Again, such a folder will still have isTrashed==false (which is abysmal).

Bug reports have been lodged (thanks to @DalmTo for the link) via: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Defect,API-Drive

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4003
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4004

SO, the question: know a way around these issues?

UPDATE:

I've narrowed these problems down to my personal Google account (or my personal Drive, which has many, many files in it). That suggests these issues are symptoms of or closely related to https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3905

Comment: If you are reporting a bug you should put it on the issues not hear this is for helping with programing issues https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Defect,API-Drive

Comment: https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037 is a good place to post

Comment: @pinoyyid my experience with that g+ community is that one can post, but  don't expect anyone to care.

Comment: @seanpj AFAIK those are as up-to-date as possible. Android SDK Manager has Google Play Services 26 installed, gradle has compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.0' (the latest version according to gradleplease.appspot.com), and android devices have Google Play Services apk v7.8.99. It is Android's/GooglePlayServices job to throw popup to entice user to update as necessary, so while there are newer versions released (e.g. v8.1.04 dropped today) I (and eventual end-users of the app I'm working on) must rely on Google to update as needed.

Comment: The issue tracker is the correct place to post issues with metadata syncing, which all of these issues seem to be related to. We'll follow up there - thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 2):

I can give you some points regarding the issue 1/ (syncing on multiple devices running the same app). I've been pointing out this already in [April 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073474/google-drive-android-api-changeevent-listener-workings) without satisfactory answer (actually resounding silence). So I switched back to the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) and handled everything myself (using syncadapter, service, ...). The REST's algorithm is:

1. create/update/delete/ .... (execute() method)
2. dispatch resource ID ('id'+message) using GCM to other devices
3. let other devices deal with the change through the REST API (again, in service)

I've re-visited the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) a few times since and never got satisfactory results (requestSync). Finally, I got half-way happy when started to use '[completion events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269)' (a year later, needless to say).

Again the algo is:

1. create ....
2. get ResourceId from completion
3. dispatch 'ResourceId'+message using GCM to other devices
4. let other devices deal with the change through the GDAA (using the ResourceId)

... and the point is:
During the time I was trying to make it work, I finally realized that the GDAA *is not well suited for all applications* (like the one we're discussing here). The GDAA goes through all kinds of hoops and loops to make the online/offline state transparent and at the same time to cache data and optimize network traffic, battery use, ...  It creates latency, unpredictable states...

... so, in the end I stopped blaming the GDAA for not being a swiss-knife and do everything everybody ever dreamed up. It is up to the developer to FULLY understand the advantages / drawbacks of a toolbox he/she is using and decide upfront which tool to use. I know, the docs do not spell it out and believe me, I myself got caught in Magnus's excitement. I still remember [*pinoyyid's*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369573/trash-delete-in-new-google-drive-android-api) warning in January 2014, telling me not to jump in too early.

Good Luck

Comment: False advertising is still false advertising. It's cost me time, which comes at the cost of my client, their client, and end-users. Determining that the GDAA is falsely advertised as providing certain features while not delivering said features is necessary for me to justify the time I've spent. Begrudgingly, it is highly likely I will have to move to using the Drive REST API (for Java). I'm unable to add GCM to the system's architecture, so hopefully text searches for folder/file names will suffice even with the REST API.

Comment: I foolishly assumed that GCM-like functionality is build into GDAA since the very beginning (requestSync). And I was lucky that I had the luxury to waste time slowly discovering the ins and outs.

Comment: I've had a breakthrough! The problems I'm seeing are isolated to my personal Google Account (well, my personal Drive and probably anyone else who has many files and/or used Drive for a long time). My code can access shared files across multiple android and iOS devices using new or lightweight-users' accounts (i.e. not many files). So this seems very much related to https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3919

Answer (score 0):

As per your response on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4003), we believe this is an issue with sync for your particular account, potentially related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3905). We'll continue discussion of this issue on the issue tracker.