# Check if folder exists, and create it if not

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I notice that there is not a conclusive answer to this on SO, so I am looking for a canonical answer to the question "**How to check if a folder exists, and create it if it does not, using the Google Drive Android API?**". Ideally showing examples of both the asynchronous approach using `ResultCallback`, and the synchronous approach using `.await()`.

P.S. I am aware of [this question with the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713482/google-drive-android-api-check-if-folder-exists), but the accepted answer is focussing on the known bug of lag on `isTrashed()`, and is not clear about at which point in the code you actually know the folder exists. Other answers seem out of date.

Answer (score 9):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530855/google-drive-android-api-deleted-folder-still-exists-in-query) - while focussing on the laggy deletion status issue - does provide a pattern for testing if a folder exists.

Using an asynchronous callback:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
    .addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.eq(
            SearchableField.TITLE, "MyFolder"),
            Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)))
    .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Cannot create folder in the root.");
        } else {
            boolean isFound = false;
            for(Metadata m : result.getMetadataBuffer()) {
                if (m.getTitle().equals("MyFolder")) {
                    showMessage("Folder exists");
                    isFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!isFound) {
                showMessage("Folder not found; creating it.");
                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("MyFolder")
                    .build();
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet)
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result) {
                        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
                        } else {
                            showMessage("Created a folder");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Using a synchronous `.await()`

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
    .addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.eq(
            SearchableField.TITLE, "MyFolder"),
            Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)))
    .build();

    DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result = Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
        .await();

    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        showMessage("Cannot create folder in the root.");
    } else {
        boolean isFound = false;
        for(Metadata m : result.getMetadataBuffer()) {
            if (m.getTitle().equals("MyFolder")) {
                showMessage("Folder exists");
                isFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!isFound) {
            showMessage("Folder not found; creating it.");
            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("MyFolder")
                    .build();

            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .createFolder(googleApiClient, changeSet).await();

            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
            } else {
                showMessage("Created a folder");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to update file inside a folder  if already exits?

Comment: @Atula Sorry, I haven't done any Android in 6 months and I really don't remember how it works :(

Comment: I m using your async code and it was working fine earlier but now it started giving false folder existence sometimes, any idea to fix?

Comment: @Panache I don't know what you mean by "giving false folder existence" can you explain more? Also, I don't really understand this is code because I copied it from the liked Answer, plus it's been almost a year since I've done Android dev, so I might not be able to answer anyway.

Comment: @Panache If the folder is in the trash, the folder exists

Answer (score 0):

Your quote:

> ... is not clear about at which point in the code you actually know the
>   folder exists

In the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) Api, you wait for a response from the '*ecexute()*' method. Straightforward, and you can time the response out. You get folder/file id (ResourceId) and you know it exists in the Drive.

In [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro), look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269). Again, when you get completion notification with a valid ResourceId, you know that the folder/file is 'up-there'.

Good Luck