# Not Same return of folder existence at google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I used this code in my app to check folder exist or not and if not create it. Code is giving correct result some times and some time shows false folder existence. Most of time, when I connect to google drive first time, it shows folder exist and if I try to connect again, it creates folder. What is missing in this, why not stagnant result is being achieved. I m using asynchronous method.

[Check if folder exists, and create it if not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851649/check-if-folder-exists-and-create-it-if-not)

Comment: It could be the offline/sync nature of GDAA

Comment: You may want to check this related SO post - [Google Drive Android API - Check if folder exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713482/google-drive-android-api-check-if-folder-exists) wherein it also includes checking of trashed folders and see if it will help. As mentioned, you may want to also check this [thread](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/3) for additional information.